# How to mobilize all links with http://www.google.com/gwt/x?u=?

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile, prefix

I've trying to make the links on some of my pages "mobilized" with this great service Google Mobilizer: http://www.google.com/gwt/x?u=

Is there a way to prefix all of the links within a div or element, so rather than the link be site.com/link it becomes http://www.google.com/gwt/x?u=site.com/link ?

I'm thinking that something like this might work:

```
if (window.location == $LINK)
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/gwt/x?u=" + $LINK;
```

I'm just not sure how to code it. If you know how it's done I would be very thankful!

Comment: The new address for the transcoder is http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=[ your_website_URL]

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be useful for you:

1. Download the file [`Mobile_Detect.php`](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) at GitHub
2. Put it on the root of your server
3. Put this code at the beginning of every page you would redirect

   ```
   <?php
   include('Mobile_Detect.php');
   $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
   if ($detect->isMobile()) {header('Location: http://www.google.com/gwt/x?u=http://' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],PHP_URL_PATH . '');}
   ?>
   ```

I tested it with [this site](http://www.onlinecasinoselite.com/) and works fine

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this [Google Mobilizer bookmarklet as I had a itch to scratch](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2012/04/google-mobilizer-bookmarklet-view-just.html).

You can adapt the code to suit your requirement.